# Have an inline element line wrap only after taking up the full width of the page (on its own line)?

Tags: css, html

It seems like normally when you have two inline elements and resize the page down, the second element line-wraps to the next page like this:

[image: Second element that line-wraps at the end of the page]

---

However, is there a way to force it onto its own line first, and then line-wrap normally from there?

[image: Second element moved to its own line to look nicer]

---

If I set the second element to `white-space: nowrap`, this *seems* to work fine, until the second element is too large to fit on a single line:

[image: Second element moved to its own line to look nicer but then runs off the edge of the page]

---

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: Second element moved to its own line to look nicer and then wraps nicely at the end of the page]

[image: Second element on the same line]

---

Can this be done using HTML and CSS only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block;` seems to do the trick:

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2u9s3a8b/)

```css
span {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span id="first">First Element</span>  <span id="second">Second Element Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro.</span>
```